# In Amazon S3, other user doesn't see the same buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I've set up a couple of S3 buckets, which I can see if I navigate to Storage > S3 in the console:

[image]

I've also added permissions to another account, e.g. for the `lucy-dev2` bucket:

[image]

However, this user, when he navigates to Storage > S3 in his console, doesn't see the same 'directory list' of buckets.

Ultimately, we would like all users to see the same buckets. How could we set this up?

(I've perused https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html, but it seems this should be possible without using the CLI?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The S3 console does not show you buckets that you have access to (nor does `aws s3 ls`). It shows you buckets in the AWS account associated with your login credentials (assuming that you have permission to list buckets).

The user in the second account can, however, access these buckets, assuming the correct permissions:

- awscli: `aws s3 ls s3://lucy-dev2 --region us-east-1`
- S3 console: visit
  [s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/lucy-dev2](https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/lucy-dev2/?region=us-east-1)
  while logged in.